# How to get objects for a month in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

I have an array and this array contains `Observation` type element which has a `date` property in it.

I just want to get all the elements depending on the month and year.

Suppose if I have a date 01/11/2015, so I want to get all the elements from the `observationList` which have month 11 and year 2015.

The sample code is as below,

```
class  Observation
{
  var date:NSDate = NSDate()
  var value:String = ""
}

var observationList = [Observation]()
```

suppose that the above `observationList` has the element then how will I get all the element for e.g. *November, 2015?*

Comment: Use `NSDateComponents` for that. You need an instance of `NSCalendar` to get the date components from a date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter your array

```
var observations = [Observation]()
```

with the `filter` method like this

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let filteredObservations = observations.filter { (observation) -> Bool in
    let components = calendar.components([.Month, .Year], fromDate:observation.date)
    return components.month == 11 && components.year == 2015
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed put by @dasdom you need a NSCalendar to get the components of an NSDate.

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar() // you can also ask for a specific calendar (e.g Gregorian)
let components = calendar.components([.Month, .Year], fromDate:date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an extension to get your date components:

```
extension NSDate {
    var month: Int {
        return NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!.component(.Month, fromDate: self)
    }
    var year: Int {
        return NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!.component(.Year, fromDate: self)
    }
}
```

Then you can easily filter your dates as follow:

```
class  Observation {
    var date = NSDate()
    var value = String()
    init(date: NSDate, value: String) {
        self.date = date
        self.value = value
    }
}

let ob1 = Observation(date: NSDate(), value: "Testing")

let observationList = [ob1]

let filteredList = observationList.filter(){ $0.date.year == 2015 && $0.date.month == 12 }

print(filteredList.first?.value ?? "")   // Testing
```